# How and Where to create new Laravel project at Azure microsoft

Tags: azure, laravel-5

I'm deal with azure for the first time, i'm try to create new Laravel project with Azure microsoft, at first i install the composer, then i create new project on site folder, how can i show the Welcome laravel page on my browser? that means what URL should i enter?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using an App Service: **[the name you entered when you created your App Service]**.azurewebsites.net.

If you don't remember it, locate your App Service in the Azure Portal and the URL will be displayed in the top right of the Overview blade.

Comment: when i enter this: https://MyAppName.azurewebsites.net/
it shows me this error:
Server Error in '/' Application.